My Shopify App Block Modal Position is Wrong
I’m making a Shopify app block using Vue 3 and TailwindCSS, but I’m stuck with a modal issue.
what happened:

The modal uses position: fixed and should open relative to the browser window (top-0, left-0).
Instead, it’s aligning to the product section, not the window.

Weird Part:

It works fine on a US-based VPS, but on my PC and other devices, it doesn’t work.
I’ve checked the HTML and CSS in the browser inspector, and they look the same.
I even tested in Chrome’s Guest Mode (no extensions, no cache), but the issue is still there.

How can I fix the modal so it always positions relative to the browser window on every device?
I’ve attached screenshots of the problem.
Thanks so much for your
https://i.sstatic.net/KHxMqpGy.png
https://i.sstatic.net/Jfu6VdV2.png

To get help quicker you would need to provide some code, and/or a link to the store.
